# Configure Pentaho BI to use MySQL as default repository

Tags: server, pentaho

I'm trying to configure Pentaho to use MySQL as Default BI repository on Pentaho Community Edition 8.x

I applied all the setting as per the official documentation from Here.

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Installation/Archive/MySQL_Repository

Default Pentaho is shipped with HSQLDB its working. But configuring to MySQL i'm getting this error:

```
2018-12-23 16:22:11,291 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.security.userrole.CompositeUserRoleListService] User/Role List could not be obtained.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target of Bean was never resolved: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder$1.invoke(BeanBuilder.java:159)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)


Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener
```

Can someone please help me out. What steps I'm missing out?

Really appreciate
Thanks So much,

Answer (score 2):

Your error is just misconfiguration in one or multiple files. Just following the official docs didn't work for me.

I found an blog with a concise explanation on what to do, it's in spanish, hope it works for you.

MySQL
https://ingmmurillo-dwh-bi.blogspot.com/2015/10/configuracion-de-pentaho-bi-server-v54.html

PostgreSQL
https://ingmmurillo-dwh-bi.blogspot.com/2018/06/configuracion-de-pentaho-server-8x-para.html

P.S.: My scenario was Pentaho 8.1 with PostgreSQL 9.6, 9.4